# Getting an error. Need to add favicon in my child theme functions.php. What's wrong?

Tags: child-theme, favicon

When I put this code in my functions.php

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'my_favicon');
function my_favicon() {
    echo "<link rel='shortcut icon' href=' " . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .
         '/images/favicon.ico'"'>";
}
```

I get

> [Message from webpage]: There has been a critical error on this website. Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: where did you add this code? what is the full text of the error message?

Comment: @Michael  The error was when a reload the webpage.                                          
[Message from webpage]: There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.    I put this line of code in my functions.php. `code` **add_action('wp_head', 'my_favicon');
function my_favicon()
{
 // echo "<link rel='shortcut icon' href=' " . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/favicon.ico'"'>";
} ** `code`

Comment: The sequence of quotes after ico looks wrong to me. What were you trying to do there/ Why not just `ico'>";` ?

Comment: You've got a syntax error: that `'/images/favicon.ico'"'` should be `"'/images/favicon.ico'`. And the `href` should have no whitespace at the beginning, so use `href='"`.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for editing my question.I am a noob lol. Looks alot better. Very Clean.

Comment: @SallyCJ That got rid of the error. But, it is showing a blank favicon. The image does exist. hmmm...

Comment: Sorry @JerryFleurival, I meant, `"/images`. But why don't you just use the [Customizer → Site Identity → Site Icon](https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-favicon/) to set the site icon (or favicon)?

Comment: @SallyCJ Awesome that fixed it. Thank you so much.  Muneeb solved it too. I'm aware of using Customizer. I'm just a person who likes to know everything under the hood. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_favicon');
function my_favicon() {
    echo "<link rel='shortcut icon' href='" . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .
         "/images/favicon.ico'>";
}
```

I think the problem was incorrect quotation marks on the string.
Can you try this code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Muneeb! It was the quotation marks not being right. It worked. 

Comment: you are welcome :)